# Get line number of a python function call in exception

Tags: python, exception, logging, error-handling, traceback

I have a function like this

```
def try_strip(s):
    try:
        return s.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # (I've tried inspect, traceback, logging, sys)
```

and if I call it somewhere like this

```
try_strip('could be a string or not')
```

then the exception line number would be the one in which the try_strip is defined.
Is there a way to get info about where was it called? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Traceback module which is included with Python provides this functionality. According to its documentation it:

> provides a standard interface to extract, format and print stack traces of Python programs. It exactly mimics the behaviour of the Python interpreter when it prints a stack trace.

The function `traceback.format_stack()` will return the stack trace information you need as a list of strings while the function `traceback.print_stack()` will print the stack trace information to the console. Below I have included some code which shows how you might use this in the example you provided:

```
import traceback


def try_strip(s):
  try:
    return s.strip()
  except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_stack()
    stack_trace_info = traceback.format_stack()
    #  Code that write stack_trace_info to a log could go here

try_strip(5)  # This will cause an error at runtime
```

For additional info on the Traceback module, please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html .